# Assigning a selector to a UIImageView in customViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, selector

I'm using a custom cell in storyboard which contains unknown number of UIImage controls. I created UIImage controls like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *SubCellIdentifier = @"MultiEmailCell";

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self
                                          action:@selector(imageTapped:forIndexPath:)];

        tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < contact.emailArray.count; i++) {
        UIImageView *selectedEmailState     = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                               CGRectMake(268, (20 + (i * 50)), 32, 32)];
        selectedEmailState.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected_None.png"]
        selectedEmailState.tag = (i+1)*1000+1;
        selectedEmailState.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [selectedEmailState addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
        }
```

I want to create a selector for each UIImageView with two parameters, when I tap a UIImage in current cell, selector parameters would be tag of tapped UIImage and current indexPath. How can I implement this?

this is hierarchy of my tableView

[image: hierarchy]

I want to know which UIImageView is tapped and in which cell it is located.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign tag to each image. then you can identify the image by its tag & hence can know which image is tapped. Let me know if this is not what you need

**tag**
An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag
```

The default value is 0. You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the view later.

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

[UIView tag reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag)

**`– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`**  This method is called when a row is selected in tableview. To know which row is selected, use

```
int row= indexpath.row;
```

Comment: in addition to tag of UIImageView, I have to know the indexPath of current cell.

Comment: Is your code working upto the extent you have mentioned here?

Comment: Yes, I've simplified my code a little bit for viewing purpose. But yes, it works fine.